# Immutability of String in JAVA

Tags: java, string, garbage-collection, immutability

Consider the code :

```
public class Stringer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "SomeLine";
        System.out.println(s1);  // prints SomeLine
        s1 = "AnotherLine";
        System.out.println(s1);  // prints AnotherLine
    }

}
```

When I change `s1` from `SomeLine` to `AnotherLine` , since Strings are Immutable , does this mean that `SomeLine` is lost and is eligible for GC ?

Much appreciated

Comment: This has nothing to do with immutability. It has to do with changing references.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798403/string-is-immutable-what-exactly-is-the-meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When I change `s1` from `SomeLine` to `AnotherLine`, since Strings are
>   Immutable, does this mean that `SomeLine` is lost and is eligible for
>   GC?

The fact that `String` is immutable is irrelevant to your question. The fact that you are reassigning the variable and therefore losing the other reference is what determines if the object is a candidate for GC or not.

To answer the question, it would be if it wasn't a [`String` literal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class
>   String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings
>   that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned"
>   so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

That `String` object won't be garbage collected because the `ClassLoader` and the corresponding class have a reference to it.

Related reading:

- [What is the difference between "text" and new String("text")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext-in-java)

Comment: this is not that trivial. Interned Strings could be easily reclaimed by GC. http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html

Comment: @Eugene Right. I wanted to emphasize the concept of `String` literal rather than `String` interning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you're right, it does become eligible for garbage collection. This is because you are no longer referencing the original string with your variable.

Here is a related question on SO:

[Aren't String objects in Java immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398118/arent-string-objects-in-java-immutable)

Answer (score 1):

It is not that trivial when talking about Strings in Java. Even if the String is interned **it can still** be garbage collected. In java 6, even if it is allocated in the permgen, it can be garbage collected, in Java 7 they are allocated on the Heap and are still eligible for GC.

**Usually** interned Strings are not eligible for garbage collection because the class has a reference to it. But what if that class was loaded dynamically (Class.forName)? It could easily be the case when that Class could be unloaded, thus *an interned string could be reclaimed by GC*.

See an example [here](http://www.codeinstructions.com/2009/01/busting-javalangstringintern-myths.html) that shows that interned strings could be garbage collected.